# Failed to compile: Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my component class I have created a constructor but its throwing error:

Component class with constructor:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.state = {
    temp: 0,
    desc: '',
    icon: '',
    loading: true
  }
}
```

the error I am seeing :

```
./src/App.js
  Line 5:  Parsing error: Unexpected token, expected ";"

  3 | import './App.css';
  4 | 
> 5 | constructor(props) {
    |                    ^
  6 |   super(props);
  7 |   this.state = {
  8 |     temp: 0,
```

Can someone please advise if I am missing something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not familiar with React, but from what I know of ES6, `constructor` is only valid within a `class` definition.

Answer (score 2):

There is no class. It's just a function.
Try this.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';

class YourComponent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
         super(props);
         this.state = {
              temp: 0,
              desc: '',
              icon: '',
              loading: true
          }
     }
}

export default YourComponent;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use class based components, like:

```
  import React from 'react';

  class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        temp: 0,
           .
           .
           .
       }
     }
   }
```